# Offshore Wind Assessment

Tags: time-series, distributions, sampling, latin-hypercube

Does anyone know if Latin Hypercube sampling can be effective in the statistical analysis of offshore wind time series in order to reproduce random wind fields with a small amount of observed data?

Generally, can we apply Latin Hypercube sampling on any level of wind speed distribution analysis (macro-meso-on site)?